# possible to populate list view from cursor row id?

Tags: android

is it possible to populate a listview based on a row Id from a custom cursor adapter. I keep getting an error "illegalArguementException column: _id does not exist". but the database has it and is already being used correctly. I don't know what to do, because I would need to populate different listviews from the same database and i don't want to have to create multiple database which will still have the same column names. Any ideas will be greatly appreciated. thanks

HERE is the database code is being cold:

```
public Cursor retrieveItemRow(long Id){
        open();
String[] Columns = new String[] {TITLE,DATE, TIME};
Cursor row = db.query(true,DATABASE_TABLE, Columns, KEY_ID +"=" +Id, null, null, null, null,null);
    if(row != null){
    row.moveToNext();
    return row;
    }
    return row;
      }
```

Here is a method i am trying to call it in:

```
 public void fillRowData(long Id) {

Cursor cursor = adapter.retrieveRow(id);
startManagingCursor(cursor);
String[] from = new String[]{DBAdapter.TITLE, DBAdapter.DATE, DBAdapter.TIME};
int[] to = new int[]{R.id.Name, R.id.Date, R.id.Time};

customCursor items = new customCursor(this, R.layout.viewlist, cursor, from, to);
setListAdapter(items);          

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you include _id in the SELECT statement represented by the Cursor you pass into your adapter.  For example, if I were using the `SimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to)`, my `Cursor c` would originate with something like "SELECT _id, name FROM users;".

From the [Notepad Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/notepad-ex1.html):

```
private void fillData() {
     // Get all of the notes from the database and create the item list
     Cursor c = mDbHelper.fetchAllNotes();
     startManagingCursor(c);

     String[] from = new String[] { NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE };
     int[] to = new int[] { R.id.text1 };

     // Now create an array adapter and set it to display using our row
     SimpleCursorAdapter notes =
          new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.notes_row, c, from, to);
     setListAdapter(notes);
}
```

The tutorial defines a method in the database helper class that returns all of the `Note` objects.  Essentially they're using `SQLiteDatabase`'s `query` method that returns a `Cursor` object.  The query's select string is where you should include the _id column.

So in your case, you need to add `KEY_ID` to your `Columns` String array variable, because those are the columns that are included in your select statement (db.query()).  This is also hinted at in the [CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html) documentation:

> The Cursor must include a column named
>   "_id" or this class will not work.

Comment: sorry to bother, but am slightly confused. do i include the select statement in the database class where am calling the cursor or in the adapter. please any link to an example on this would be appreciated.

Comment: I just updated my initial response, check it out and let me know if that makes sense.

Comment: i already have a listview that is populated from a listview. what i want to do now is populate another listview with the rowId i have already obtained. like Cursor c = mdbHelper.fetchNote(rowId). this is where i get the error.

Comment: What are the select statements that you are using?  Post all of the code that is useful in debugging the situation.

Comment: i don't use any select statement in the code. i have added the database code that is causing the problem.

Comment: Check out my edit -- the query() method is your abstracted select statement.

Comment: oh thank you very much!! works great.. never payed attention to that statement "The Cursor must include a column named "_id" or this class will not work." and i had it in another method.  Bad Student!!  :(

Comment: Haha awesome!  Mark the answer as accepted when you get a chance to let others know that a solution was found.